# Eclipse can't find Java, Java not installed

Tags: java, eclipse

I was following an online tutorial on how to delete JVM 6 and install JVM 7 to be able to run eclipse on my Mac running OS X 10.9.2. First I installed the latest JDK.
I was instructed to type the following commands to delete JVM 6.

```
sudo rm -rf /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/

sudo rm /private/var/db/receipts/com.apple.pkg.JavaForMacOSX*

sudo emacs /Library/Receipts/InstallHistory.plist
```

Then, I set the symlinks for java 7, with these commands.

```
sudo rm /usr/bin/java

sudo ln -s /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_60.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java /usr/bin/java
```

This should be it. Now my computer does not have any version of Java on it:

the command "java -version" responds with "java: command not found"

I also cannot direct to the folder with cd Library/Java responding with "Folder does not exist", however I can browse to that folder manually.

Can someone please assist me in getting Java 7 running on my computer so I can use eclipse.
Any help much appreciated and keep in mind I'm a Mac newb.

this is the tutorial i followed:

http://www.cc.gatech.edu/~simpkins/teaching/gatech/cs2340/guides/java7-macosx.html

Comment: You don't need to have Java on the command line to use it in Eclipse. Just go to Prefs->Java->Installed JRE-s and add the path to your currently downloaded installation.

Comment: @blgt Eclipse itself needs Java to boot.

Comment: `/usr/bin/java` is normally symlinked to `/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current/Commands/java`

Comment: @logoff AFAIK it ships with its own JRE. Now that I think about it, it should be possible to use that, too.

Comment: @blgt Eclipse does not ship with a JRE. You can set up an Eclipse RCP to include a JRE but Eclipse itself does not do this.

Comment: @blgt eclipse does not ship with JRE, it has its own compiler for java so for compiling/executing programs its not necessary to have JDK (in most cases till you are not developing web apps or using automated builds), but it is necessary to have JRE to run eclipse

Comment: please explian better this sentence "I also cannot direct to the folder with cd Library/Java responding with "Folder does not exist", however I can browse to that folder manually.". what does mean you can browse to it manually? have you created the folder from root?

Comment: @greg-449 Huh, I guess that had me confused. Looked it up now, and yes you're right. Thanks

Comment: Oh sorry guys, from terminal the command "cd Library/Java" comes up with nothing...on the other hand, I am able to direct to that folder in my finder (Macintosh HD->Library->Java ... etc.) @logoff

Comment: use "cd /Library/Java", first slash is very important as it is an absolute path.

Answer (score 1):

Did you change the PATH variable to point to the newer version?

`/usr/libexec/java_home` is the starting point for switching java versions on the command line. Check out this post to understand how to handle different java versions on the Mac.

Answer (score -1):

I think that the folder still exists but executables didn't existe because anh version of Java is installed.
Normally you have just to download the jdk or jre on oracle web site and run the package downloaded

Comment: This is not a solution to the problem.